# Why does my app crash on "indexPath.row" load?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, nsindexpath

I may not be providing enough information to properly ask this question, but I am trying to discern why I am getting a crash when my code reaches the loading of `indexPath.row`.

With much of the code truncated, here is my **TableViewController.swift**:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return minions.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return minionCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}

    func minionCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> MinionCell {

        let minion = minions[indexPath.row]

        //Set the cell to be the custom, reusable, MinionCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(minionCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MinionCell

        if let name = minion.name {

            cell.nameLabel?.text = minion.name

        } else {

            cell.nameLabel?.text = "No data available."

        }

        return cell
    }
```

From what I can discern, the `let minion = minions[indexPath.row]` is throwing an error, with the error occurring on `__Thread 1__` and the syntax showing:

> function signature specialization Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed

The console output seems to show nothing indicating what the error may be, though I'm questioning if this has to do with my transition to Swift 2 from Swift 1.2.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the minions array is populated before that line? Could be that the table data is not ready at that point. I think you might get more help if you post a complete test case somewhere so that people can run it themselves. Just create a test project with your tableview which illustrates the problem. Then put it on github or similar.

Answer (score 0):

problem should be with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier,Ensure it is set properly in storyboard.Best place to give identifier name for your cell is, your minioncell class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this issue by altering;

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return minionCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}`

to

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

By altering the **return** function and adding all of my table cell configuration to this function, I found complete success in properly populating the table.